# How do I modify the shape of an aircraft wing?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, edges

I have imported an aircraft from Sketchfab into Blender 3.0 and I would like to change the shape of the wing ends to the shape on the drawing. What methods should I use to move the vertices so that the wing remains smooth and even? I tried dragging and pushing the edge vertices in proportional edit mode and it kind of works but the result does not look great.

Any suggestions how to modify the wing would be most welcome. The wing has a curve when looking at the end profile ie a wing shape.
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Proportional Editing should work fine, you could also deform the object with a Lattice modifier or Mesh Deform modifier

Comment: did you try proportional editing?

Comment: @moonboots: you must have been 4 secs quicker :) actually 2... ;)

Comment: @Chris, i can always answer before you, thanks to my DeLorean

Comment: @Ivan Fet, I see, actually it may not work well for the front of the wing, the topology is a bit too dense, can't you simply redo the wing?

Comment: Thanks Moonboots. You are correct about the front of the wings being the problem. Proportional editing works okay for stretching the wing in place but pushing the wing into a curve does not work well. I was hoping there was an easy way to modify the existing wings and not recreate them.